# Is there an opposite method to DataType.mapToString(Map<String, Object> m) in Pig API?

Tags: api, apache-pig

I need to convert a pig formatted map string representation (e.g. "['k1'#'v1','k2'#'v2']") to Map object.
I'd prefer using pig implementation rather than implementing it myself.
I found a method for an opposite conversion: DataType.mapToString(Map m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really stick to Pig, you may come up with the followings:

```
...
import org.apache.pig.builtin.Utf8StorageConverter;
...
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String mapStr = "[k1#v1,k2#v2]";

        Utf8StorageConverter converter = new Utf8StorageConverter();
        Map<String, Object> map = converter.bytesToMap(mapStr.getBytes());

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " :: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you have Pig v0.10.0